# Insert images in database

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload, spring-data-jpa, image-upload, spring-data-jpa-datatables

I'm making a real estate app in spring boot - thymeleaf and I really need to ask you how to store images. I was thinking about making a table just for images and anotate it manyToOne, and insert it into Property entity because one property can have 10,15,20 images and that is the part I know how to do.

But I'm not sure how to handle the rest of the code. How to make file upload in the /add method?
And also howadd and show them in thymeleaf?

This is my /properties/add method without the option of inserting images:

```
    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public String add(Model theModel) {
        Property theProperty = new Property();

        User theUser = new User();
        theProperty.setUser(theUser);
        List<User> userList = userService.findAll();

        Address theAddress = new Address();
        theProperty.setAddress(theAddress);
        List<Address> addressList = addressService.findAll();

        theModel.addAttribute("property", theProperty);
        theModel.addAttribute("user", userList);
        theModel.addAttribute("address", addressList);

        return "properties/property-form";
    }
```

I don't expect you to type it but maybe somebody know the most similar project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you wanna store the images directly to the database but having a table as a reference to the image itself.

You can do it the same way as you are doing with the userList.

```
theProperty.addAttribute("images", imageList);
```